# Can I have a deploy with only publicly mapped frontend?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, single-page-application, vuejs3, sveltekit

I want to make a web application using two independent codebases - backend build with spring boot and frontend build with sveltekit.

Also, I want only the frontend endpoints to be publicly available when the whole stack is deployed.
(E.g.: to avoid any form of direct or spam attacks towards backend's API)

Is that possible?

I am confused because all of the examples I found use `localhost` to fetch backend API; and never e.g.: a public IP address.
If I have a component like this (pseudo-code):

```
ShowUserListComponent extends Component {
    val users = null
    
    fun fetchUsers() {
        users = axios.fetch("localhost:8080/users")
    }
    
    render() {
        <button onClick={fetchUsers}>
        foreach(user in users) {
            <div>{{ user.name }}</div>
        }
    }
}
```

What is the request/response and data flow here? Something like?:

- user visits the address `www.my-cool-page.com`
- sveltekit downloads the whole app (HTML, CSS, javascript) to the client (is this how SPA works?)
- user navigates to `/users` route -> browser locally changes the component to `ShowUserListComponent`
- how does the local component fetch the data, if the backend's API is not public?

Answer (score 1):

This is what `CORS` (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) is used for. You can tell your backend server which domains can access which routes. Thus preventing URLs you didn't authorize to hit your API.

You can find a guide on how to enable `CORS` for spring here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: But does this mean that the backend's API needs to be public? And even then, if components run on client devices, then the backend should allow all of the origins(=IP addresses), no?

Comment: @milkamar So your frontend will be hosted somewhere, lets say you host your front-end on `www.my-app.com`, then you can tell the backend to only allow requests from `www.my-app.com`, when someone tries to access the backend from another URL, it wouldn't work.